# How to include or exclude specific namespaces in cluster role kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, fluent-bit

I am trying to create a daemonset that will collect logs from all the pods in a node from a specific namespace. I am not sure how I would specify a namespace name.

I have a namespace logging in which i deploy the daemonset. I created a serviceccount as below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: fluent-bit
  namespace: logging
```

My cluster role looks like this

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: fluent-bit-read
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources:
  - namespaces
  - pods
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
```

role binding

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: fluent-bit-read
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: fluent-bit-read
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: fluent-bit
  namespace: logging
```

Right now the daemonset collects logs from the path `/var/log/containers/*.log` which currently has log files from containers running in all namespaces.  Is there a way I could restrict this daemonset to just collect logs from namespaces i need ?

Comment: Your question and title are unrelated. Fluentd/bit log collection is entirely unrelated to Kubernetes RBAC.

Comment: fluentbit is running as a daemonset in kubernestes cluster i want to restrict this to read only logs from certain namespaces

Comment: @vkr why does my answer do not answer your question?
You should use a Role instead of ClusterRole as ClusterRole is cluster wide and cannot be namespaced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what we have in k8s documentation ([link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole)).

> A Role always sets permissions within a particular namespace; when you create a Role, you have to specify the namespace it belongs in.
>
> ClusterRole, by contrast, is a non-namespaced resource. The resources have different names (Role and ClusterRole) because a Kubernetes object always has to be either namespaced or not namespaced; it can’t be both.

So, in your case you need to make use of a **Role** and a **RoleBinding** instead of a ClusterRole and ClusterRoleBinding.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to adjust your Bit config to only read the log files you want. Or you could use routing rules if you prefer. This is not related to the Kubernetes API, Bit reads the logs directly off the disk via a bind mount.

Answer (score 0):

## `ClusterRole` with `RoleBinding`

A `RoleBinding` can also reference a `ClusterRole` to grant the permissions defined in that `ClusterRole` to resources inside the `RoleBinding`'s namespace.

This kind of reference lets you define a set of common roles across your cluster, then reuse them within multiple namespaces.

### Create `RoleBinding` yaml

Use `RoleBinding` instead of `ClusterRoleBinding`

Create file with below content and save as `rb.yaml`

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: fluent-bit-read
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: fluent-bit-read
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: fluent-bit
  namespace: logging
```

### Apply `RoleBinding`

Apply the yaml file

```
kubectl apply -rb.yaml -n [namespace]
```

Let say you want restrict `daemonset` on *logging* `namespace`

```
kubectl apply -rb.yaml -n logging
```

### Reference

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60960500/21099211 by [@Juliano Costa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9291851/juliano-costa)

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole